# MySQL - Set table as default if empty prefix

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, left-join

I have a code I did not write. It includes a specific SQL query.

For my personal use, I would like to partially alter it with a LEFT JOIN to another table, but with minimum code change.

Problem: there are several ambiguous fields.

As the SQL query is pretty big and comes dynamically from other functions in the original code, it annoys me to prefix all ambiguous fields.

My question is: is there a way to only prefix the new table from my LEFT JOIN and make MySQL consider fields with no prefix as table A?

Example:

```
SELECT id, table2.fieldB FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = id WHERE id > 10;
```

Where all "id" occurences without prefix are linked to table1.

If not, what are my other solutions?

Basically, I don't want to touch the big condition because it's dynamic and comes from other functions in the code and I don't want to alter it everywhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should qualify all column names.  That is simply a good practice and it makes the code easier to understand and maintain.

That said, you do not need to qualify column names that are used in joins if you use the `USING` clause.  In fact, you shouldn't qualify such names.  So, you can safely write:

```
SELECT id, t2.fieldB
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     USING (id)
WHERE id > 10;
```

Note:  For the `USING` clause to work, the column(s) needs to have the same name in both tables.  I consider this a best-practice anyway -- that foreign keys have the same name as primary keys (which generally would not be a simple `id`).

Also, you can use table aliases to reduce the amount of typing when qualifying column names.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, in my case, the two fields have different names so I cannot use USING.

Comment: @Jachinair . . . In the example in your question, they have the same name.